# AppleScript or Safari add-on to highlight text

Tags: macos, safari, script, text, highlights

I have some variable that I would like to highlight in Safari.

I was thinking AppleScript, but I can use something else otherwise.

I'm using a Chrome plug-in which does the same, any idea how to do that?

[image]

Comment: Searching works for single words, not for multiple if they are present separately.  Also, I exchanged AS tag with Script, as [tag:javascript-automation] can also be used for the same